# Populate Table with two MySQL Loops

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, while-loop, populate

I have 3 tables called: TableA, TableB, TPopulate

The tables: A,B have some rows i need to populare the table (TPopulate) without a Stored Procedure for Example PSEUDOCODE:

```
@loop1 = 1;
@loop2 = 1;
WHILE loop1 <= (Select COUNT(*) FROM TableA)
    WHILE loop2 <= (Select COUNT(*) FROM TableB)
        INSERT INTO TPopulate (column1, column2) VALUES (TableA.column1, TableB.column1)
    END;
END;

TableA Represent (users)
TableB Represent (Privileges)
TPopulate Represent (Users_Privileges)
```

What I try to do is insert all privileges to all existing users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use loops at all. You should be thinking in terms of SETS when using a relational database.

Here is the correct way to achieve this. First using the CROSS JOIN to create a cartesian set of all the combinations of ids from tableA and tableB. Then inserting that entire set into TPopulate

```
INSERT INTO TPopulate (column1, column2)
SELECT  T1.PKField
        ,T2.PKField
FROM    TableA T1
CROSS JOIN
        TableB T2
```